# angular2 material theming does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material2

1) I created this file src/theming.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber , 700, A100, A400);

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent)
```

2) I added this to .angular-cli.json

```
 "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "theming.scss",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

3) Oh dear...my themimg is not showing..its a a yucky gray...

```
<button mat-button  color="primary" (click)="add()">Add Point!</button>
```

Logic would dictate that the color should be light blue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your theme in `angular-material-theme`. Do the following at the end of your `theming.scss` file:

```
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```