# Angular 2+ theme button colors not working

Tags: angular, themes

I have a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdzuv9)
that I believe is set up following the [Angular theming documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), and yet the colors in the following code are not displaying:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
<button mat-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
```

What's more, I'm brand new to stackblitz and can't find where the body tag is (it's not in index.html?!), so I assigned the my-app tag the class,"mat-app-background":

```
<my-app class="mat-app-background">loading</my-app>
```

I have looked through several SO entries (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599971/angular2-material-theming-does-not-work))and github issues pages (e.g., [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1798)), and none seem to be relevant to my issue or current. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

All you forgot here was to import `MatButtonModule` like:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

and then off-course in import array

```
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatButtonModule ]
```

in your `app.module.ts` since you have single module here.

Also, be sure to import a theme too in styles.css

`@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Here's [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-br6yw3)

Answer (score 2):

I added material to my project(**Angular 9**) by using `ng add @angular/material` and faced the same problem.

To fix it, I add to add below the dependency manually to the `package.json`:

`"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.2"`

Hope this will help anyone facing issue with newer versions or using `ng add` command.

Answer (score 2):

For me buttons are working fine in **Angular 12**, but buttons are showing **white in color**(colors not applied eg: primary etc..)

command :

```
 ng add @angular/material
```

working fine for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart the application once it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

did the trick for me (Angular 12). Also, import locations have changed:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```